# Marshalling fails with exception about MarshallerImpl not known to this context

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I have a relatively simple package of 8 Java classes generated from an XML schema using JAXB XJC. I also have a utility class to marshal and unmarshal instances of the class.

### This works

The utility class can successfully unmarshal a valid XML document into an instance of the ‘root’ class `WordMergeInfo`. For example this works fine:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(WordMergeInfo.class);
    Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    return (WordMergeInfo)um.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

### This doesn’t work

But marshalling to a string fails. In this code:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(WordMergeInfo.class);
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    m.marshal(m, writer);
    return writer.toString();
```

the call to `Marshaller.marshal` fails with the following error:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:482)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
```

As I understand it, `nor any of its super class is known to this context` means that a JAXB class needed for marshalling cannot be found. So why can’t one of the JAXB implementation classes be found, when the same class is in the stack trace?

### Context

This error showed up in a unit test of my class, run under Maven. The dependencies are:

- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1
- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.13

I got the same error with earlier versions of these (2.0 and 2.0.3, respectively).

The Maven test class path is:

```
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\Workspace\DARTCorrModule\xml\target\test-classes
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\Workspace\DARTCorrModule\xml\target\classes
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.1\jaxb-api-2.1.jar
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\javax\xml\stream\stax-api\1.0-2\stax-api-1.0-2.jar
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.1.13\jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.8.5\mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\javax\ejb\ejb-api\3.0\ejb-api-3.0.jar
C:\Users\mstra.CUSTMAN\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.4\slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> nor any of its super class is known to this context

This means that the class is not registered as a marshallable class in the JAXB context.

Your error is on this line:

```
m.marshal(m, writer);
```

You are trying to marshal the marshaller itself. You probably meant to marshal a `WordMergeInfo` object.

Comment: Thank you @casablanca for a quick answer and for spotting my stupid coding mistake. It is all good now!